# First homology group of torus glued to a sphere in 3 points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have to compute the homology groups of a space $X$ constituted by a sphere attached to a torus in 3 distinct points. Basically the space in the picture.
[image]

I tried used the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Obviously we can choose the open cover $\{U,V\}$ in such a way that:

$$U\sim S^1\times S^1, V\sim S^2, U\cap V \sim \{P,Q,R\}$$

where $\sim$ is homotopy equivalence. I managed to compute all of the homology groups except the first one. When I try to calculate the first one, I get this short exact sequence:

$$0\to H_1(U) \to H_1(X)\to R^2 \to 0$$

My idea is trying to prove this sequence splits (since I think $H_1(X)$ should be $R^4$ where $R$ is our coefficients ring). But I can’t find a nice surjection $X\to V$. Can you help me?

Comment: $H_0(U\cap V)$ is free so any short exact sequence splits, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module

Comment: How do you get that short exact sequence? The map $H_0(U\cap V)\rightarrow H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V)$ is not zero.

Comment: @Thorgott you are right I should have wrote the kernel of that map instead that is isomorphic to $R^2$. Now I've corrected

Comment: @KentaS okay but is it really necessary to use axiom of choice? Is there a constructive way to show this?

Comment: @Kandinskij I am not saying use axiom of choice. Given an exact sequence of the form $0\to M\to N\xrightarrow p R^n\to 0$, for each generator $e_i\in R^n$ choose a $x_i\in N$ such that $p(x_i)=e_i$. Now, one may define a splitting $s\colon R^n\to N:e_i\mapsto x_i$.

Comment: Correct. Also, the left term should be $H_1(U)$ instead of $H_1(V)$.